# Groupby in pandas returning too many rows

Tags: python, r, pandas, tidyverse

I am trying to filter a dataframe in pandas, using the groupby function. The aim is to take the earliest (by date)instance of each variable for each id.

Eventually I was able to solve the problem in R using tidyr like so:

```
  df_mins <-  df %>% 
   group_by(id, variable) %>%
   slice(which.min(as.Date(date)))
```

I also achieved something close using pandas which looked like this:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'variable'])['date'].transform(min) == df['date']
```

however the resulting df had more than one (non unique) entry per variable. any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: It would be better if you could post sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have duplicate for min date

```
m=df.groupby(['id', 'variable'])['date'].transform(min) == df['date']
df=df[m].drop_duplicates(['id', 'variable'])
```

Also in R we can do

```
df=df[order(df$date),]

df=df[!duplicated(df[c('id', 'variable')]),]
```

Same in pandas

```
df=df.sort_values(['date']).drop_duplicates(['id', 'variable'])
```

Comment: Sorry, Ive updated the question for clarity. The problem i have is not that there are duplicates but there are multiple, non unique entries for each variable, whilst there should be one for each.